# Get status code for given a timeout and url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ping

I am working on a ruby on rails application.I want to ping the URL with a given timeout and interval.I was able to get status code using curl and even with net/http without specifying the timeout.
This works fine without timeout :

```
%x{curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" "URl" -o /dev/null}
```

Can I know if there is any other way or modification to this

Comment: I know that with Nokogiri you can rescue any errors and read that as a page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188195/mechanize-ruby-read-source-code-of-404-page